# Can we make nextjs render the last "parent component" available instead of 404 page?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Imagine i have a tree like this in pages folder

- pages

  - app.tsx
  - test

    - index.tsx

When i type "http://localhost:3000/test/test1" and hit enter. I want nextjs render "test" component instead of 404 page. Can we do that?

Comment: Instead of rendering a specific component, it might be better (and possible) to use a redirect: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#redirect in a page like `/pages/test/[test].tsx`

Comment: Have you looked into using [`redirects`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects) in your `next.config.js`?